# How to load jQuery in mediawiki?

Tags: jquery, mediawiki

I would like to use jQuery in my wiki.

I checked this page (http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/JQuery) and it says I should use ResourceLoader to include jQuery. (I use MediaWiki 1.17.0)

But I could not get how can I do it using ResourceLoader.

Comment: I cannot event find thing what I should do in the concrete in MediaWiki 1.17.0

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you can't find `/resources/jquery/jquery.js`?

Comment: I can find it there, but I cant find how to load it in wiki pages (adding script tags in header section) by using ResourceLoader.

Comment: What are you doing, are you creating an extensions?

Answer (score 3):

As explained [in the MediaWiki manual page "ResourceLoader/Migration guide (users)"](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/ResourceLoader/Migration_guide_%28users%29):

```
mw.loader.using( ['jquery.cookie'], function () {

/* some other script that uses $.cookie from jQuery*/

} );
```

You have to use either `load()` or `using()` and select the appropriate jquery modules depending on what you need to do.

Comment: Where should I write it in? In script tag? I got '''Uncaught ReferenceError: mw is not defined''' error...

Comment: Dude, I need some explanation on what you are trying to do. Are you creating an extension? Do you know how to create an extension? If not, read about it first, because you're asking questions that you need answers for further down the line.

Comment: I'm editing skin file based on the Monobook skin. I would like to use jQuery in my skin, and trying to import it.

Answer (score 2):

As of Mediawiki 1.17 jQuery is loaded up by default already.

See: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/JQuery